# Scrolling X-axis with pyqt5

Tags: python, plot, python-3.5, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Presently I am working on a GUI that has incoming data from an Arduino and it is being plotted. Right now it is being plotted against the last 50 samples. I have found a way to get the X-axis to increase in size, however I would like it to shift as the data came in, that way it can be a representation of time rather than samples that have been seen. I would also like to see how I can put a x-axis label. I have tried the matplotlib method and it didn't work.

```
class GUI(QWidget, Ui_DynoTest1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, border = None):

        # This is what is used to make the graph.        
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.thread = GetData(self)
        self.thread.dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)
        self.thread.start()
        self.torque = []
        self.horse_power = []

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.plot.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.graphicsView.setLayout(layout)

        self.p1 = self.plot.plotItem
        self.p1.setLabels(left='Torque')
        self.TorqueCurve = self.p1.plot()
        self.TorqueCurve.setPen(pg.mkPen(QColor(0,0,0), width=2.5))

        self.p2 = pg.ViewBox()
        self.HorsePowerCurve = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        self.HorsePowerCurve.setPen(pg.mkPen(QColor(0, 0, 255), width=2.5))
        self.p2.addItem(self.HorsePowerCurve)
        self.p1.scene().addItem(self.p2)
        self.p1.showAxis('right')
        self.p1.getAxis('right').setLabel('HorsePower', color='#0000ff')
        self.p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(self.p2)
        self.p1.vb.sigResized.connect(self.updateViews)
        if len(self.torque) < 50:
            self.torque.append(Torque)
        else:
            self.torque[:-1] = self.torque[1:] + [Torque]

        if len(self.horse_power) < 50:
            self.horse_power.append(HorsePower)
        else:
            self.horse_power[:-1] = self.horse_power[1:] + [HorsePower]

        self.TorqueCurve.setData(self.torque)
        self.HorsePowerCurve.setData(self.horse_power)
        self.updateViews()
```

Comment: From what I understand you want the x axis to vary for example: 1,2,3, ... 50, and an instant after 2,3,4, ... 51 and another time 3,4,5, .. ., 52. I am right?

Comment: The code you provide doesn't define `pg`.  What is that?

Comment: @PaulCornelius pg is pyqtgraph

Comment: @eyllanesc you would be correct I like the frame size but I think it would be nicer to have the x-axis shift like the graph does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a pyqtgraph you pass as data only a list this will place the x axis, but if we pass the two axes the use our axis for it we must create a list that provides the time for it we use a variable that saves the initial time.

If you want to place a label for x you can use one of the following modes:

```
self.p1.setLabels(left='Torque', bottom='Time')
self.p1.setLabel('bottom', 'Time', units="samples")
```

In the first you can indicate all labels and in the second is individually.

```
class GUI(QWidget, Ui_DynoTest1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        [...]
        self.torque = []
        self.horse_power = []
        self.time = []
        self.counter = 0
        [...]
        self.p1 = self.plot.plotItem
        self.p1.setLabels(left='Torque', bottom='Time')
        # self.p1.setLabel('bottom', 'Time', units="samples")
        [...]

    def onDataChanged(self, Force, RPM, Max_RPM, Torque, Max_Torque, HorsePower, Max_HorsePower, Run_Time):
        [...]
        if self.counter < 50:
            self.torque.append(Torque)
            self.horse_power.append(HorsePower)
            self.time.append(Run_Time)
        else:
            self.torque = self.torque[1:] + [Torque]
            self.horse_power = self.horse_power[1:] + [HorsePower]
            self.time = self.time[1:] + [Run_Time]
        self.HorsePowerCurve.setData(self.time, self.horse_power)
        self.TorqueCurve.setData(np.array(self.time), self.torque)
        self.updateViews()
```

Comment: By replacing the If else statements with with what you have starting with `t1=` the graph does not update. If I leave the if else statements in and add the `t1=` it does scroll but it still isn't in line with time the time elapsed. I know that it is based on the number of samples I have coming in, so if I slow my sample rate down that should slow the x-axis but I feel there has to be a way to set the `Run_Time` to be the X-axis or for that matter any other variable like say force or rpms.

Comment: @MatthewEspindolaMunn Do not replace it just add it in the end, I updated my answer.

Comment: That is what I tried doing first, however that is what results in the x-axis not being the same as time. It does have the scrolling X-axis, but I was hoping that I could get the x-axis be any variable that I wanted it to be not just the samples that have been undergone.

Comment: @MatthewEspindolaMunn already modify my answer, check my answer

Comment: That seemed to work fantastically! Now if I wanted to change my X-axis to some other variable, I would go and replace everything that is `.self.time` with `self.variable` and at the end replace `Run_Time` with whatever variable I chose?

Comment: Yes, I recommend studying programming, I think this will be my last help since I see that every time you have a little one you do not investigate. Try to investigate and test, take a course, invest your time.

Comment: I appreciate all the help you have given me thus far, however I was wrong is saying that the graph worked perfectly. Perhaps I wasn't very clear. So my desire is to have the graph display the most recent 50 seconds worth of data and have the X-axis coincide with that. Presently what the graph does is it shows all of the data. So if the program has ran for 5 minutes it shows the data from start to 5 minutes. What I want is the x-axis to be like 50,51,52,..,100 if say 100 seconds have past. Sorry to bother you this one last time.